# os x snow leopard install xcode in chroot

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode, chroot

I'm trying to build a chroot environment for testing developer builds of some software. I need xcode installed in this chroot to build it, but the xcode package from the snow leopard install dvd will only install to the / target. Is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the CM_BUILD env var before running installer.  In the terminal do this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/chroot
export CM_BUILD=1
sudo installer -target /tmp/chroot -pkg /Volumes/Xcode\ Tools/Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg
```

I'm working on a project, called joot, to automate creation of chroots.  It currently supports only linux, but I'm working on OS X support right now.  See http://getjoot.org/